# 90s PC space game where the enemies resembled Imperial probe droids

Tags: story-identification, video-games, space

I have been trying to find a 90s pc space game.  All I can remember is that your spaceship was in the middle of the screen and enemies that looked like Imperial probe droids. (But they were not and it was definitely not a *Star Wars* game.) The noise they made when communicating was "lak tak lac tak".

I think it was maybe mid 90s.

Comment: Do you remember if you used the mouse to move? Keyboard? Joystick?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What was the game mechanic?  Was the ship fixed in the centre (like *Asteroids*) or was there movement but the screen moved to follow (like *Defender*)?  Was movement in 2 dimensions or just one?  Could the ship rotate?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11995/how-to-ask-a-good-video-game-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Star Control? ...